# Get value if key exists in list of dictionary

Tags: python

I have a python list like

```
[{'month': 8, 'total': 31600.0}, {'month': 9, 'total': 2000.0}]
```

and want to generate it like

```
[
  {'month': 1, 'total': 0},
  {'month': 2, 'total': 0},
  ...
  {'month': 8, 'total': 31600},
  {'month': 9, 'total': 2000},
  ...
  {'month': 12, 'total': 0}
]
```

for that, I'm running iteration on the range `(1,13)`

```
new_list = []
for i in range(1, 13):
  # if i exists in month, append to new_list
  # else add total: 0 and append to new_list
```

How can I check if **i** exists in **month** and get the dictionary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert your list of dict into direct month: total mapping with

```
monthly_totals = {item['month']: item['total'] for item in data_list}
```

and use a simple list comprehension with `dict.get` to handle missing values:

```
new_list = [{'month': i, 'total': monthly_totals.get(i, 0)} for i in range(1, 13)]
```

Comment: Excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new list containing the default values and then update the needed values from the original list

```
>>> lst = [{'month': 8, 'total': 31600.0}, {'month': 9, 'total': 2000.0}]
>>> new_lst = [dict(month=i, total=0) for i in range(1,13)]
>>> for d in lst:
...     new_lst[d['month']-1] = d
... 
>>> pprint(new_lst)
[{'month': 1, 'total': 0},
 {'month': 2, 'total': 0},
 {'month': 3, 'total': 0},
 {'month': 4, 'total': 0},
 {'month': 5, 'total': 0},
 {'month': 6, 'total': 0},
 {'month': 7, 'total': 0},
 {'month': 8, 'total': 31600.0},
 {'month': 9, 'total': 2000.0},
 {'month': 11, 'total': 0},
 {'month': 12, 'total': 0}]
```

Comment: As you can see from the printout, you have an off-by-one error. Indexes are 0-based so you need `d['month'] - 1`.

Comment: @Zastai. Thanks.. Corrected my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
exist_lst =  [{'month': 8, 'total': 31600.0}, {'month': 9, 'total': 2000.0}]

new_lst = []

for i in range(1,13):
    found = False
    for dict_item in exist_lst:
        if dict_item['month'] == i:
            new_lst.append(dict_item)
            found = True

    if not found: 
        new_lst.append({'month': i, 'total': 0}) # default_dict_item

print(new_lst)
```